# How can I hide files with certain extensions in nvim and Mac?

Tags: vim, latex, neovim

I'm a vim and latex user. Each time the tex file is compiled, many annoying files emerge with pdf file, like .aux, .log, .out etc, rendering the nvim and Mac files messy.

How can I hide those files in both vim and my iMac?

Comment: Have a look at ltx2any. One of the key concepts of this latex automatisation tool is to keep your folder clean

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a Makefile wich will take care of all deletions. Once I wrote a book and that was its makefile:

```
# Based on http://wikiri.upc.es/index.php/A_Makefile_to_compile_Latex
# by: Joenio Costa <joenio@perl.org.br>
#
############################### FILES ###############################
#
# DOC: the document

DOC = vimbook

############################### PROGRAMS ###############################

TEX = pdflatex
RM = rm -f
MAKE = make

########################################################################

$(DOC).pdf:
    $(TEX) $(DOC).tex
    bibtex $(DOC).aux
    $(TEX) $(DOC).tex
    makeindex $(DOC).idx
    $(TEX) $(DOC).tex

clean:
    $(RM) $(DOC).aux $(DOC).log
    $(RM) $(DOC).toc $(DOC).lot $(DOC).lof
    $(RM) $(DOC).ttt $(DOC).lot $(DOC).fff
    $(RM) $(DOC).blg $(DOC).out
    $(RM) $(DOC).dvi $(DOC)-*.dvi
    $(RM) $(DOC).ps $(DOC)-*.ps
    $(RM) $(DOC).tex.backup
    $(RM) $(DOC).tex.bak
    $(RM) $(DOC).bbl
    $(RM) $(DOC).pdf
    $(RM) $(DOC).tex~
    $(RM) $(DOC).bib~
    $(RM) Makefile~
    $(RM) *.ind *.ilg *.idx *.aux
    $(RM) texput.log core

show:   $(DOC).pdf
    evince $(DOC).pdf

shownew:    clean   $(DOC).pdf
        evince $(DOC).pdf
```